# Counting vowels in strings in java doesn't count the first string

Tags: java

Here is the code I wrote in Java to count vowels (a, e, i, o, u, y) in n strings:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class VowelCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = x.nextInt();
        int[] count = new int[n];

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if(x.hasNextLine()) {
            String str = new String(x.nextLine());
            int counter = 0;

                for(int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {

                                    char ch = str.charAt(j);

                                    if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U' || ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y') {

                                        counter += 1;

                                    }

                        }

                count[i] = counter;
            }

        }

        for(int k = 0; k < n; k++) {

            System.out.print(count[k] + " ");

        }


    }

}
```

If I insert 10 strings like:

> (hello, hi, string, int, double, boo, ad, ok, def, rep)

it should return

> 2 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 1 1

but what it returns is

> 0 2 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 1

so it count the first one as the second and doesn't count the last one (in fact right after writing "def" in the console it runs the code and prints the solution in console.

Can you help me figure it out where I am wrong? It would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `.nextInt()` doesn't finish to read all the line, so your first call to  `x.nextLine()` catch the space after the int.

Just add a line after : `x.nextLine();`

```
int n = x.nextInt();
int[] count = new int[n];
x.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like standard hackerrank format. I believe most of the templates include code to read the data - if one problem doesn't, just copy code from one that does.

I'm guess the problem here is that `nextInt` does not read the line ending. The first `nextLine` just reads the newline after the count.

```
    int n = x.nextInt();
    int[] count = new int[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(x.hasNextLine()) {
        String str = new String(x.nextLine());
```